# Can't load a file in Play (always not found)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I can't load a file in Play:

```
val filePath1 = "/views/layouts/mylayout.scala.html"
val filePath2 = "views/layouts/mylayout.scala.html"

Play.getExistingFile(filePath1)
Play.getExistingFile(filePath2)

Play.resourceAsStream(filePath1)
Play.resourceAsStream(filePath2)
```

None of these works, they all return `None`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to read a source file at runtime.  Which is not something you should usually do.  If you want to read a file at runtime then I'd recommend putting it somewhere that will end up in the classpath and then use `Play.resourceAsStream` to read the file.  The files in the `conf` directory and non-compiled files in the `app` dir should end up in the classpath.

Comment: is it safer to use Play.resourceAsStream only?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to load a file.

Comment: `getExistingFile` works in both cases, `resourceAsStream` still doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the file?  You shouldn't need to read a template file directly.  Those are source files.

Comment: It's not important what I'm trying to do with it! This is just an example!

Comment: The reason why I'm asking is because you seem to be trying to read a source file at runtime.  I'm trying to figure out if that is what you actually want to do.  I can't really think of a reason to do that.  So having more information about what you are trying to achieve will help me provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: ok, it's reading an html file in order to send it as an email (in html format). - "/views/layouts/emails/mylayout.scala.html" I guess it should be "/views/layouts/mylayout.html"

Comment: Thanks for the added info.  Personally I would use the compiled template to generate the email body.  Then it is just a function you can call with parameters if needed.

Comment: Yes, but it says "object mylayout is not a member of package views.html.layouts.email" for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: Given a file `app/views/layouts/mylayout.scala.html` try to call: `views.html.layouts.mylayout().body`